# How to select mixed results at every n-th row?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a product table here

```
product_id, popularity, date_add
```

I would like to SELECT products and sort by popularity, and having new products sprinkled in every 5 rows (5,10,15,...). With the ability to select again as page 2. The output should be something like this.

```
popularity #1 
popularity #2 
popularity #3 
popularity #4
latest #1
popularity #5
popularity #6
popularity #7
popularity #8
latest #2
popularity #9
popularity #10
popularity #11
popularity #12
latest #3
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: @SaucedApples Seriuosly, I wouldn't even know what to try for this one.

Comment: Get 40 results from your popularity statement, get 8 results from the latest table, mingle them in code where you need them....if you really need them in sql - you could do something with `SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 10, 50` , `UNION ALL` and raise the parameters to limit. Use the same for the latests table

Comment: @SaucedApples I don't have any clue on how to do this on a mysql query alone. I could do it with PHP coding (thanks Patrick), anything easy and fast are good.

Comment: see answer - tried to show what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDL:

```
create table Te (product_id int, popularity int, date_add int);

insert into Te (product_id, popularity, date_add)
values
(1,      10,               1),
(2,      21,               1),
(3,      12,               1),
(4,      23,               1),
(5,      5,                1),
(6,      2,                5),
(7,      3,                6),
(8,       1,                7),
(9,       1,                1),
(11,      210,            11),
(12,      221,            11),
(13,      212,            11),
(14,      223,            11),
(15,      25,             11),
(16,      22,             15),
(17,      23,             16),
(18 ,      21,             27),
(19,       21,             31);
```

SQL (which is easy to build using loops and whatnot)

```
(select * from Te order by popularity desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0) 
UNION ALL
(select * from Te order by date_add desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) 
UNION ALL

(select * from Te order by popularity desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5) 
UNION ALL
(select * from Te order by date_add desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) 
UNION ALL

(select * from Te order by popularity desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 10) 
UNION ALL
(select * from Te order by date_add desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2) 
UNION ALL

(select * from Te order by popularity desc LIMIT 5 OFFSET 15) 
UNION ALL
(select * from Te order by date_add desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3)
```

Result:

```
product_id  popularity  date_add

    14        223        11
    12        221        11
    13        212        11
    11        210        11
    15        25         11
    *19       21         31
    17        23         16
    4         23         1
    *16       22         15
    *19       21         31
    *2        21         1
    18        21         27
    *2        21         1
    3         12         1
    1         10         1
    5         5          1
    7         3          6
    17        23         16
    6         2          5
    9         1          1
    8         1          7
    *16       22         15
```

You'll have duplicates as you see by the id, you maybe want to filter those....

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer to my own question.

No, I still couldn't do it by pure SQL.

So far, I was able to do this by adding an extra column named "sorting". With this additional column, I could sprinkle anything I want into the list. And the query is simple and fast.

The only downside is the extra work to update the sorting value. But it can be done easily by crontab at every hour or so.